# Keyboard not showing in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am calling

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                      name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

method in `viewDidLoad`, but keyboard dos not appearing when i click on web view.

can anybody tell me why is this happening

Comment: Starting with iOS 6 you can use [keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the keyboard show up be calling *anything* on the notification center. You need an UI element that can handle text input (for example an `UITextField`, a `UIWebView` can't handle text input by itself) and than call

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]
```